# Trace minimization with additional constraint on $X$

Tags: matrices, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming, linear-matrix-inequality

Consider the following SDP problem:
\begin{align*}
\min_X \; & \mathrm{Tr}[AX]\\
\mathrm{s.t.}\; & X \succeq 0\\
& X \succeq \begin{bmatrix}0 & 0.5\\0.5 & 0\end{bmatrix},
\end{align*}
where $A$ is positive semidefinite.
I know that the minimum is equal to $0$ if the only condition is the first constraint. Numerically, I know that there is a closed-form solution to this problem, which is
\begin{equation*}
0.5(\sqrt{A_{11}} + A_{12}),
\end{equation*}
but I can't derive it from the above problem.

Comment: Which matrix $A$ did you use in your numerical experiments?

Comment: In my case it consists of first- and second-order moments of a scalar random variable, i.e. $A = \begin{bmatrix}\mu^2 + \sigma^2 & \mu \\ \mu & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: In this case, the matrix $A$ is positive definite. This changes a lot because if it would be positive semidefinite, there would exist $X\ne 0$ such that $\mathrm{Tr}(AX)=0$. Could you please clarify that? Also, where did you find the closed-form solution?